# Dynamically add <div> inside <input>

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to add `<div>` inside `<input>`

```
<input type="submit"  
  name="body_0$main_0$contentmain_0$maincontent_1$contantwrapper_0$disclamerwapper_1$DisclaimerAcceptButton"
  value="I understand and agree to all of the above "  
  onclick="return apt();"  
  id="DisclaimerAcceptButton"
  class="DisclaimerAcceptButton">
```

The button is too long so I want to split its caption into two lines.
I don't have access to pure html since everything is dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

[`input` elements cannot have descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4):

> ```
> <!ELEMENT INPUT - O EMPTY              -- form control -->
>                     ^^^^^
> ```

However, if you can change the code that generates the button, you can use [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) instead:

```
<button name="body_0$main_0$contentmain_0$maincontent_1$contantwrapper_0$disclamerwapper_1$DisclaimerAcceptButton" onclick="return apt();" id="DisclaimerAcceptButton" class="DisclaimerAcceptButton"> 
    I understand and agree to <br />
    all of the above
</button>
```

This lets you style the content of the button however you want to.

Comment: That won't work though with the ASP.NET Button component, which the `name` and `id` attributes bespeak the use of.

Answer (score 2):

A `div` is a block level HTML element and it shouldn't be added inside the button in such a way. You can however use CSS to specify a `width` to the button, and thus acquire the multi-lineness that you're looking for.

Comment: Also, for legacy support in browsers such as Internet Explorer 6, you can use the HTML-representation of carriage return: `&#13;&#10;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add div inside of input element (unless you want it in input's value).

Answer (score 1):

No can't do. And if it works on some browser, it's not guaranteed to work anywhere else, because it doesn't follow the standards.

Answer (score 0):

Only you need:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a"/>
<label for="a"><div>... div content ...</div></label>
```

Like somebody write in input you cannot put any element but in label for it can.